# Wix: How to remove GAC files marked as Permanent

Tags: wix

A previous version of an MSI marks some GAC files as permanent, now I want to remove those files upon upgrading to a newer version of the same program. Is it possible to do this using Wix code or do I have to always manually delete the files ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know that you can ever fully delete the component since it's permeant but you can remove the file.

I tested this by creating a component called Client.exe and a component called Server.dll which was marked Permanent="yes" and Assembly=".net".

```
 <DirectorySearch 
        Id="SERVERFOLDER" 
        Path="[WindowsFolder]Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Server\v4.0_1.0.0.0__bb771c317b736a07" AssignToProperty="yes">
      </DirectorySearch>
    
 <RemoveFile Id="oldfile" Property="SERVERFOLDER" Name="Server.dll" On="both"/>
 <RemoveFolder Id ="old" Property="SERVERFOLDER" On="both"/>
```

The remove File/Folder elements are added to the Client.exe component.

This results in Server.dll being removed from the GAC.  But I do have to ask,  why bother?   A file in the GAC has a strong name and shouldn't break anything that doesn't reference it.  Also it's not something that takes up much disk space or anything the user really sees.